# express 3 bodyParser fail to deode the data during sending data with image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a registration page where I have to upload email and location and profile picture at the same time. I got all the data and images but without decoding the email value and location value in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.

I am sending the following data

```
  {
  adminId: '53db417f6d8c0afb2d4986d1',
  eventId: '53db417f6d8c0afb2d4986d2',
  name: 'Abhi',
  email: 'abhi7294@gmail.com',
  companyName: 'abhisek',
  designation: 'engineer',
  location[Baddress]: '25 Sarat Chandra Dhar Road Kolkata - 90',
  type[0] = 1,
  type[1] = 2,
  type[3]['decodingTest'] = 4
  }
```

with profilePicture Image.

I am getting the folowing result : -

```
{
    adminId: '53db417f6d8c0afb2d4986d1',
    eventId: '53db417f6d8c0afb2d4986d2',
    name: 'Abhi',
    email: 'abhi7294%40gmail.com',
    companyName: 'abhise',
    designation: 's',
   'location%5Baddress%5D': '25+Sarat+Chandra+Dhar+Road+Kolkata+-+90',
   'x%5B0%5D': '1',
   'x%5B1%5D': '2',
   'x%5B3%5D%5Bdecoding%5D': '5'
}
```

without body parser and image I am getting the following result : -

```
{ adminId: '53db417f6d8c0afb2d4986d1',
  eventId: '53db417f6d8c0afb2d4986d2',
  name: 'Abhi',
  email: 'abhi7294@gmail.com',
  companyName: 'abhise',
  designation: 's',
  location: { address: '25 Sarat Chandra Dhar Road Kolkata - 90' },
  x: [ '1', '2', { decoding: '5' } ] }
```

Can any one tell me what should I do to get all the data in decoded manner with image?

Comment: Did you try multipart/form-data? To upload both a binary file and other form details?

Comment: using multipart/form-data give me the same result. nothing change.